# Probability ant walking the number line

Tags: probability, recursion, random-walk

Having troubles solving this one.

> Consider an ant walking along the positive integers. At $n$ the ant moves to $n+1$ with probability $1/3$​ and to $n−1$ with probability $2/3$. If the ant reaches $0$ it stops walking. Starting from $n=3$ what is the probability that the ant reaches $n=5$ before reaching $n=0$?

So far, I've found the following:
The expected distance the ant travels with each move is: $1/3(+1) + 2/3(-1)= -(1/3)$.

Thus, if the ant starts at $n=3$, it is expected to take the ant $1/3(x) = 3 (x=9)$ moves to make it to zero.

How to further develop it to the solution?

Comment: Hint: Let p(m) be the probability that the ant reaches n=5 if he starts at m.  Then p(m) satisfies a recurrence relation with boundary conditions at p(0) and p(5).

Comment: Is the ant allowed to go beyond $5$ or will it return after reaching $5$ ?

Comment: You are in the framework of ["gambler's ruin model"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: We can draw a states diagram. Let $p_n$ be the probability that the ant reaches $n=5$ before $n=0$ starting at $n.$

First note that $p_5 = 1$ and $p_0 = 0.$Let's look at $p_4.$ There's a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance we go to $p_3$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ chance we go to $p_5.$ So $$p_4 = \frac{1}{3}p_3 + \frac{2}{3}p_5 = \frac{1}{3}p_3+\frac{2}{3}.$$

We write these equations for $p_1$ through $p_4.$ Then, solve for $p_3.$

Comment: I got it. Thanks! However, the probabilities should be the other way around due to the problem's wording. p4=(2/3)*P3 + 1/3 and the correct answer is p3=7/31.

Comment: @Alex Oh wait, my bad. Yeah, just flip the 1/3 and 2/3 and everything else should be right.